# Question: Baby Rudin Exercises 3.7

Tags: analysis

I am working on Exercise 3.7 of Baby Rudin.

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\Sigma a_n$ converges. I think that there exists an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $a_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and this can be proved by contradiction. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should it exist? If $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ then $a_n > \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}$.

Concerning your edit: The statement remains wrong. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that is defined the following way: We know that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some first $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_k} \leq 2^{-k}$. For every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we now set $ a_{n_k} := \frac{2}{n_k}$ and we set the remaining elements of $a_n$ to zero. Then:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2}{n_k} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^\infty 2^{-k+1} = \frac{1}{2}. 
$$
But clearly $a_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ is not fulfilled for the subsequence $(a_{n_k})$.

Comment: Non-strict inequality would be more appropriate.

Comment: I'll edit, thank you

Comment: If $a_n=\frac1{n}$, then how would the sum converge?

Comment: See my edit. Furthermore: There is no need to downvote. J.W. edited the question which made my answer look completely nonsensical.

Answer (score -1):

Simple counterexample: Let $S=\{n^2:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and define $$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac2k,&(k\in S),
\\0,&(k\notin S).\end{cases}$$